# O Notation and taylor series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Wolframalpha tells me that the Taylor series of the exponential function is $1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}+ O(x^3).$

[Taylor series](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20series%20exp%28x%29)

I just don't get this big O there, shouldn't this be a small o?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it's a big $O$ and that means that the remainder has the same order than $x^3$ and if we want use the small $o$ we write:

$$e^x=1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}+ o(x^2)$$
which means that the remainder is negligible compared to $x^2$.

Comment: but it's not the same order, the remainder goes much faster to infinity than $x^3$.

Comment: They have the same order in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Which goes to show.  When writing O notation, you should also say something like "as $x \to 0$" so inexperienced readers won't think $x \to +\infty$ or something.