# First principle of differentiation needs to approximate a sufficiently small integral as area?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y(t+\Delta t) = e^{- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'}y(t)$$ is the solution to the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dt} = -H(t)y$$, $H(t)$ and $y$ are scalar.

However, in showing that $$y(t+\Delta t) = e^{- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'}y(t)$$ leads to the differential equation **by first principle**, something strange happens.

First, I taylor expand $$e^{- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'} = 1 + \left(- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'\right) + \frac{1}{2} \left(- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'\right)^2 +...$$.

Therefore, 
$$ y(t+\Delta t) = y(t) + y(t)\left(- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'\right) + y(t)\frac{1}{2} \left(- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'\right)^2 + ...\\
\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}\frac{y(t+\Delta t) - y(t)}{\Delta t}=  \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}\frac{y(t)}{\Delta t}\left(- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'\right) + \frac{y(t)}{\Delta t}\frac{1}{2} \left(- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'\right)^2 + ...$$

However, from that I cannot show that:
$$\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{y(t+\Delta t) - y(t)}{\Delta t} = -H(t)y(t)$$

unless $$\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}\left(- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'\right) = H(t)\Delta t$$. But I do not think that's true and there must be another more rigorous argument. What went wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This proof uses "Little-o" notation. (read on wikipedia for it's definition and properties)

let's start with $y(t+\Delta t)$, and let's develop it:
$$
y(t+\Delta t)=y(t)+y'(t)\Delta t+o(\Delta t)
$$
now let's tackle this, using the intermediate value theorem for definite integrals:
$$
e^{-\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'}y(t)=e^{-H(t+\theta \Delta t)\Delta t}y(t)
$$
where $\theta \in [0,1]$ is chosen appropriately.
Let's develop it now:
$$
e^{-H(t+\theta \Delta t)\Delta t}y(t)=[1-H(t+\theta \Delta t)\Delta t +o(\Delta t)]y(t)=
$$
$$
=y(t)-H(t+\theta \Delta t)y(t) \Delta t +o(\Delta t)y(t)
$$
now let's put equal the two taylor developments:
$$
y(t)+y'(t)\Delta t+o(\Delta t)=y(t)-H(t+\theta \Delta t)y(t) \Delta t +o(\Delta t)y(t)
$$
simplify:
$$
y'(t)\Delta t+o(\Delta t)=-H(t+\theta \Delta t)y(t) \Delta t +o(\Delta t)y(t)
$$
develop the $H$:
$$
y'(t)\Delta t+o(\Delta t)=-H(t)y(t) \Delta t+o(\Delta t) 
$$
divide by $\Delta t$:
$$
y'(t)=-H(t)y(t)+o(1) 
$$
take the limit $\Delta t \to 0$:
$$
y'(t)=-H(t)y(t)
$$

Comment: Why does the constant term $o(1)$ vanish in the last step?

Comment: you must look again at the definition of $o(\cdot)$... wrt to a limit in $x_0$:
$g \in o(f) \iff \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=0$
so o(1) wrt to a limit $\Delta t \to 0$ is the set containing functions of $\Delta t$ whose limit is 0 when $\Delta t \to 0$

Comment: this problem looks like a problem in mathematical physics, perhaps in that context using the notion of infinitesimal is allowed (as it proven that they exist and follow consistent rules in non-standard analysis), and you could just perform the proof this way:
$$e^{-\int_{t}^{t+dt}H(t')dt'}y(t)=(1-H(t)dt)y(t)$$ and so on...

Comment: In $y(t+\Delta t)=y(t)+y'(t)\Delta t+o(\Delta t)$, does $o(\Delta t)$ contain only terms that have coeffificent $(\Delta t), (\Delta t)^2, (\Delta t)^3$? Is $y(t+\Delta t)=y(t)+y'(t)\Delta t+o(\Delta t)$ valid only for $\Delta t << 1$$?

Comment: $o(\Delta t)$ contains terms that are of higher order than $\Delta t$, and the equality is valid for any $\Delta t$.
if you remove the $o(\cdot)$ then those equalities will be valid for "small" $\Delta t$...
you can think of the o's like this (informally):
$$o(1) = c_0 \Delta t + c_1 \Delta t^2 + \cdots$$
$$o(\Delta t) = k_0 \Delta t^2 + k_1 \Delta t^3 + \cdots$$
like a remainder of order higher than the argument

Comment: by definition the correct way to deal with them is this:
$$
o(f)=\{g | \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=0\}
$$
so in our particular case:
$$
o(\Delta t^p)=\{\sum_i c_i \Delta t^i | \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\sum_i c_i \Delta t^i}{\Delta t^p}=0\}
$$
so that "o" is there to represent every possible remainder of order $>p$ that could apper in the full series expansion.

Comment: if you write it explicitly it becomes:
$$
o(\Delta t^p)=\{\sum_{i=p+1}^{\infty} c_i \Delta t^i\}
$$
I hope i explained it well enough.

Comment: some properties of o-notation used in the proof are the following:
$$o(\Delta t)+o(\Delta t^2)=o(\Delta t)$$
$$o(\Delta t)\pm o(\Delta t)=o(\Delta t)$$
$$o(\Delta t^a) \Delta t^b = o(\Delta t^{a+b})$$

Comment: In http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914876/o-notation-and-taylor-series?rq=1 , they use big O there. Is small o notation just one order down from big O?

Comment: big O means of the same order of the argument.
small o means of order negligible compared to the argument.which in a taylor development means one or more orders down.