# Difference between little o and big O notation in taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

I know I can say that:
$$
y(t+\Delta t)=y(t)+y'(t)\Delta t+o(\Delta t)
$$

But can I say that:
$$
y(t+\Delta t)=y(t)+y'(t)\Delta t+O((\Delta t)^2)
$$

In both cases, do I have to add that $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ or i do not have to?

Comment: Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation where such notations are explained :-)

Comment: @Math-fun i have read it before, but it is mostly about $n \rightarrow \infty$. I do not know if my statement is true for $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$. I think my statement is true for $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ but not for $\Delta t \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: when $n\to \infty$ then $\frac1n \to 0$; what is the problem if you here think that $\Delta t$ is like $\frac1n$?

Comment: @Math-fun I do not think there is any problem. The problem is probably some higher derivative is not bounded? But if that is the case I cannot use little $o$ in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should add $\Delta t \to 0$ to be explicit, but in general, $o(\Delta t)$ is understood to hold for $\Delta t \to 0$, so I think it is fine not to add it, but there is no harm in writing it.

To both notations you give: They talk about different things. The first one is the definition of $y$ being differentiable at $t$, iff 
$$ y(t + \Delta t) = y(t) + y'(t)\Delta t + o(\Delta t), \qquad \Delta t \to 0$$
we have that 
$$ \frac{y(t+\Delta t) -y(t) -y'(t)\Delta t}{\Delta t} \to 0,\qquad \Delta t \to 0 $$
that is $y(t+\Delta t) - y(t) - y'(t)\Delta t$ goes to zero faster then linear. The second one tells us more about this term. Not only is the convergence faster than linear, but it is quadratic. That is the second one holds iff
$$ \limsup_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{y(t+\Delta t) -y(t) -y'(t)\Delta t}{\Delta t^2} < \infty $$
Consider $y(t) = t^{3/2}$ at $t = 0$. Then $y'(0) = y(0) = 0$. Hence 
$$ y(0 + \Delta t) - y(0) - y'(0)\Delta t = (\Delta t)^{3/2} $$
which goes to zero faster than linear, but not quadratic.

Comment: Thanks. Does taylor series of $y(t) = t^{3/2}$ exist at $t = 0$?

Comment: the problem of the author is this one actually: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868381/first-principle-of-differentiation-needs-to-approximate-a-sufficiently-small-int/1868414?noredirect=1#comment3834048_1868414